# Accessing C# objects from Java Server Faces

Tags: c#, java, .net, jsf

Is this possible? How would I go about doing it? For instance if I had a person object:

```
public class Person
{
    // Field 
    public string name;

    // Method 
    public void SetName(string newName)
    {
    name = newName;
    }
}
```

How would I access Person.name from a JSP page? Would a webservice help me?

Comment: you cannot access C# classes from java, you can query for data and re-construct java object via web-service or call web-service method to manipulate with object on C# side

Comment: If you're asking about JSF, tag the question for JSF. JSP is only the view technology, which can be replaced by facelets.

Comment: My bad, Soner & Luiggi. Thanks for the input.

Thanks also to you Lashane. You set me in the right direction.

Comment: Which version of JSF are you using?

Comment: I'm not really married to any version of it, since this is just for a personal project. I have the latest that installed with netbeans a few months ago. Is there one version that would be better for this than another?

Comment: @NiteTrip if you're learning JSF, then you should use JSF 2.x at least, and it will be better to learn JSF 2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct way to do it.

First, you have to communicate your Java application with your .Net (C#, VB.net or whatever) application, probably by using Web Services. Then, in the Java application you will retrieve the data and handle it as you want/need. This is the most generic approach.

For JSF:

- You can fire the request from a managed bean or from a service layer. IMO it would be better to do it in service layer.
- After retrieving the data, you may parse it back into a POJO (Java Plain Old Object) to ease its use.
- This POJO may be set in a managed bean field, and then can be easily used in the view (JSP or Facelets, depends which one you use).

In code:

```
public class Person {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    //getters and setters...
}

public class PersonService {
    public Person findPerson(Integer id) {
        //code to retrieve the person object from web service call
        //and convert the response into Person object
        Person person = ...
        return person;
    }
}

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class PersonBean {
    private Integer personId;
    private Person person;

    public void findPerson() {
        PersonService personService = new PersonService();
        this.person = personService.findPerson(personId);
    }
}
```

In your view (minimal example):

```html
<h:form>
    Person id:
    <h:inputText value="#{personBean.personId}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Find person" action="#{personBean.findPerson}" />
</h:form>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{not empty personBean.person}">
    Person name: #{personBean.person.name}
</ui:fragment>
<ui:fragment rendered="#{empty personBean.person}">
    Person not found.
</ui:fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think web service is the only solution

Comment: -1: And how do you tie the web service call with JSF?

Comment: Reconstruct the object in java based on webservice and than access them from JSF

Comment: And from your answer: how you do that?